# Using hardware encoder from android camera hardware implementation

Tags: android, c++, android-camera, openmax

I want to use a hardware encoder to create JPEG image files from my hardware/ti/omap3/camera/CameraHardware.cpp file. Currently it uses libjpeg to do the encoding. From java code, I have hardware encoding working, but I don't know how to use it from native code. Can anyone point me in the right direction? A number of google searches have yielded no relevant results.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone was interested, I figured out how to do this by using the SkImageEncoder::EncodeStream function. It ended up being 7 lines of code. Woo hoo.